# Sony Vaio SVE1511 - screen brightness range is bigger on linux than on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, sony-vaio, brightness

I've a curious issue on sony vaio sve1511 laptop. I've found that on linux (eg on latest ubuntu 16) I can dim screen much more that on windows. To demonstrate it I've taken two photos with lowest brightness possible on windows (10) and ubuntu (16). Photos was taken on manual mode 1/20, 1.8, iso 800, and as You can see on linux I can dim screen much more... Laptop have ATI 7500/7600M card. On windows 10 I have latest drivers, I've tried older drivers from sony website but I cannot get screen bright as low as on linux.

Problem is, that minimal screen bright on windows is a little bit too much for me - It would be better for my eyes if I could dim screen for a little bit more.

[image: Windows 10 minimal brightness]
[image: Linux - Ubuntu (16) minimal brightess]

Some linux tec data:

```
[    6.310500] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    6.374350] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    6.387707] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (TURKS 0x1002:0x6841 0x104D:0x90AB).
[    6.387722] [drm] register mmio base: 0xC0000000
[    6.387724] [drm] register mmio size: 131072
[    6.387859] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[    6.387862] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF
[    6.387865] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=256M
[    6.387867] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[    6.388037] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    6.388039] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    6.388059] [drm] Loading TURKS Microcode
[    6.388180] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    6.390553] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    6.390684] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[    6.391647] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[    6.401284] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000274000).
[    6.401400] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    6.401405] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800aae58c00
[    6.401408] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800aae58c0c
[    6.401913] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002032118
[    6.401918] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    6.401919] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    6.401922] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    6.401957] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    6.401994] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    6.421516] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    6.421526] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    6.607648] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    6.607654] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[    6.607938] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.607967] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    7.274388] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[    7.338243] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[    7.338246] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    7.338247] [drm] Connector 0:
[    7.338248] [drm]   LVDS-1
[    7.338250] [drm]   DDC: 0x6560 0x6560 0x6564 0x6564 0x6568 0x6568 0x656c 0x656c
[    7.338251] [drm]   Encoders:
[    7.338252] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    7.338253] [drm] Connector 1:
[    7.338254] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[    7.338255] [drm]   HPD1
[    7.338256] [drm]   DDC: 0x6430 0x6430 0x6434 0x6434 0x6438 0x6438 0x643c 0x643c
[    7.338257] [drm]   Encoders:
[    7.338258] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY1
[    7.338259] [drm] Connector 2:
[    7.338260] [drm]   VGA-1
[    7.338261] [drm]   DDC: 0x64d8 0x64d8 0x64dc 0x64dc 0x64e0 0x64e0 0x64e4 0x64e4
[    7.338262] [drm]   Encoders:
[    7.338263] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[    7.747335] [drm] fb mappable at 0xB0475000
[    7.747338] [drm] vram apper at 0xB0000000
[    7.747339] [drm] size 4325376
[    7.747340] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    7.747341] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[    7.747455] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.341225] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    8.355116] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0


    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841]

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c001ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0040000-c005ffff

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0000000-c0ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at c1300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c1318000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at c1310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c1200000-c12fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c1100000-c11fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c1000000-00000000c10fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at c1317000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    I/O ports at 4048 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4054 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4050 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4020 [size=32]
    Memory at c1316000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at c1314000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at c0020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at c1280000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at c1100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Device 90ab:104d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at c1004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c1000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [104d:90ab]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```